# Ubuntu runs slow on netbook, how to remove and install xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I got an old `Dell Inspiron 700m` with the intent of learning about computers. I replaced the stock hard drive with a 120gb and upgraded the ram to 2gb. It took a while, but after figuring out the CPU could only handle 32bit I managed to get 32bit Ubuntu installed via DVD boot disk burned from a windows 8 computer.

However, it is very slow, typing lags and opening applications is very slow and not smooth. I'm thinking that my little laptop has trouble keeping up with Ubuntu and that I should switch to Xubuntu.

If I understand correctly, Xubuntu operates on a `XFCE Desktop Environment`. I managed to find the Xubuntu iso but cannot figure out how to create a bootable disk (working from the ubuntu laptop).

Any recommendations on how to get Xubuntu loaded, or any other recommendations ?

I'm a newby to all of this and I would appreciate as much description of terms and processes as possible, since I'm doing this to learn as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do a complete removal to install Xubuntu desktop environment, if you want to refuse from Unity at all just do the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get remove --purge unity
```

To do more thorough purge:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge unity*
```

The last one might remove Nautilus too, xfce uses Thunar by default but if you're planning on using it again after you install xubuntu-desktop just run:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

To set it as default you can run:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

And choose Nautilus as prefered one. Next install xfce:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop xfce4
```

After all of this you'll see improvements in speed but you might need also to configure it a bit as it's a different desktop environment and some applications like Ubuntu Tweak tool will not function that much as in Unity.

At the end you can run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Just to do a cleanup if any.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to install XFCE using the `xubuntu-desktop` package. Using, APT (the ubuntu package manager), you would do :

```
 apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

But I would recommend you to do a fresh-install.
If you want to create an USB stick with the Xubuntu iso you can use the `dd` command.

`dd` is used to dump data from a block peripheral from another one, here is an example (where `/dev/sdb` is the block peripheral representing the USB key):

```
 dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

XFCE is, indeed, more lightweight. But since you're on a very old configuration I would recommend you to give `Lubuntu` a shot. It's based upon  `LXDE` which is really lightweight.

Comment: Why would you recoomend a reinstall?